# SelectChildName messages from RemoteDeadLetterActorRef

Tags: akka, akka-remoting

I have two actor systems that communicate via akka remoting.

When I take a look into the JVM heap I am seeing (too) many instances of `akka.dispatch.Envelope` containing `SelectChildName` messages from `akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef`.

The retained heap of these messages is pretty large and causes memory problems.

What is the purpose of these `SelectChildName` messages? Is there a way to avoid them?

FYI This seems to relate with Disassociation errors that occur between the two actor systems.

Thanks,
Michail

Answer (score 1):

`SelectChildName` messages are used by Akka Remoting to resolve a remote actor. If you see a lot of them, there is a chance you are interacting directly with an `ActorSelection`, instead of an `ActorRef`.

Every time you send a message to an `ActorSelection`, for example (these are taken from the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/remoting.html#Looking_up_Remote_Actors))

```
val selection = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://actorSystemName@10.0.0.1:2552/user/actorName")
selection ! "Pretty awesome feature"
```

the - possibly remote - actor is resolved, and that involves exchanging of `SelectChildName` messages by the underlying Akka infrastructure.

If that's the case, try and use directly `ActorRef`s. You can obtain one from an `ActorSelection` by using the `resolveOne` method.

Citing the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection) again:

> It is always preferable to communicate with other Actors using
>   their ActorRef instead of relying upon ActorSelection. Exceptions are
>
> - sending messages using the At-Least-Once Delivery facility
> - initiating first contact with a remote system